Why after cleaning my ASP.NET project on .NET 4.6.1, my Visual Studio 2017 IDE no longer recognizes the namespaces of my projects?
I have an ASP.NET web application running on .NET 4.6.1. This application depends on other projects. And when I cleaned the main application, my VS 2017 no longer recognized the "using" namespaces of other projects.
I tried to add the references of the other projects in the main projects but that didn't solve anything.

did you remove any dlls from the build directory?

Do they come back if you rebuild? Visual Studio typically depends on the compiled binaries/object files to understand code for things like Intellisense.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
